# preprocessing time sequence

Tags: time-series, rnn, preprocessing

I have a long list of event (400 unique events, sequence ~10M long). I want to train an RNN to predict next event.

The preprocessing steps i took are:
(1) turning to OneHotEncoding using pandas:

```
vector = pd.get_dummies(sr)
```

This part takes about 15 seconds.

(2) Using a sliding window of 10, i create samples and labels as follows; 
i iterate the vector from (1), i take Xt as the label and Xt:t-10 as the data.

Code:

```
X = np.zeros((len(samples), window_size, voc_len), dtype=np.bool)
y = np.zeros((len(samples), voc_len), dtype=np.bool)

if IN_COLAB:
  loading_bar = tqdm.tqdm_notebook(enumerate(samples),desc='Build dataset',total=len(samples))
else:
  loading_bar = tqdm.tqdm(enumerate(samples),desc='Build dataset',total=len(samples))

for numpy_index, pandas_idx in loading_bar:
  x_idx = (pandas_idx, pandas_idx + window_size)
  y_idx = pandas_idx + window_size
  Xt = vector.iloc[x_idx[0]:x_idx[1]]
  yt = vector.iloc[y_idx]
  X[numpy_index] = Xt
  y[numpy_index] = yt

display(yt)
```

The problem is that the seconds part is VERY slow (25 minutes). 
Is there a better way to do this? 
a built in function of some sort?

Thx

Comment: You can utilize the Data Generator, this answer might be useful for you 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50612215/sliding-window-of-a-batch-in-tensorflow-using-dataset-api/50612726#50612726
Here is a guide for time-series windowing in Tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data#time_series_windowing

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of design patterns that are contributing to slow code:

1. Pandas is not designed for large-scale, fast data processing.
2. Your code is using a for loop which can be slow.
3. You are manifesting the sliding window before the program needs it. It might be better to create a view on the data and then manifest the data in memory only when the training needs it.

It would be better to use NumPy with [`numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view`](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html)